# Search a rectangle on googlemaps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

We have `Locations` data in Sql server database. Four points (`bounding rectangle`) are defined for each `Location`. Four points are `Bottom Latitude, Top Latitude, Left Longitude, Right Longitude`. If googlemaps falls within any area of the bounding rectangle, a marker will be plotted for that location.

We have some other locations in the database for which we have stored only `Lat Lng` and we are searching them using below query and it works!

```
SELECT   *
FROM     SomeOtherLocationsTable
WHERE    LocationLatitude >= @bottomlat  AND
         LocationLatitude <= @toplat AND
         LocationLongitue >= @leftlang AND
         LocationLongitue <= @rightlng
```

How we can search locations having four points defined for them?

Comment: Let me find a solution and then I will prove that this question is not "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

Use [`STIntersects`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933899.aspx)

Instead of Numbers you should store [geometries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280487.aspx) (then you may use the same query for POINTS and POLYGONS)

Answer (score 0):

After some `R & D`, we were able to find below solution and works for us (we need the functionality for USA locations only):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     LocationsTable
WHERE    
    NorthEastLongitudeRectangle < @SouthWestLongitudeRectangle OR
    SouthWestLongitudeRectangle > @NorthEastLongitudeRectangle OR
    NorthEastLatitudeRectangle  < @SouthWestLatitudeRectangle  OR
    SouthWestLatitudeRectangle1 > @NorthEastLatitudeRectangle
```

**We are still testing it, but hopefully it will work!**